# How can the diagonal covariance matrix be calculated?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance

Reading a paper and I cannot see why the following gives the diagonal covariance matrix. If we have two matrices $\theta$ and its mean over timesteps $\bar{\theta}$. Then according to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.02476.pdf) (section 3.3) the diagonal covariance can be calculated like this...

$$
diag(\theta^2 - \bar{\theta}^2)
$$

But I cannot explain why this would be the case. Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: Your question should be self contained as much as possible, at least not making people searching through an article of 25 pages ...

Comment: @nicomezi I gave the exact subsection of a few sentences which contains this part. This question could be answered without it as well just by my explanation but I included the paper for reference

Comment: Indeed you told the section, but the notation are meaningless if you stay in that part. That being said, he is just applying an usual formula for estimating the variance since the square of the matrices are considered element wise.

Comment: is there a name for this usual for of estimating the variance so I can see the derivation?

Comment: I am not aware of a "name", however, you have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator)

Comment: I actually just came from there and I still don't get it. I get that we are estimating the covariance, I get the section right after this in the paper where they estimate the full covariance...What I don't get is why that small formula with the diagonal is correct. It is probably a simple answer but I cannot see why it is correct

Comment: I see now, it is just a form of $\mathbb{E}[x^2] - \mathbb{E}[x]^2$